# Any use of advanced Abstract Algebra in Differential Geometry?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, soft-question

I believe that if someone is going to continue their studies and doing research on Differential Geometry's topics, would never need advanced Abstract Algebra (or maybe not even undergraduate level of it). But why in any graduate program, students must take advanced Abstract Algebra (for example the book Algebra by Hungerford) as a **compulsory** and **common** course for **any** pure mathematics program?

I don't think even advanced Abstract Algebra is needed for Real Analysis (?)

Comment: I do differential geometry and frequently use abstract algebra. But this is not the point of such a requirement. It is to make you a more rounded mathematician; I absolutely agree that *every* mathematician should know the rudiments of topology, differential geometry, analysis, algebra... even if they don't use them on a daily basis.

Comment: Lie groups is an important part of differential geometry.

Comment: I believe a broad basic knowledge is fundamental to be a good mathematician. You might not use any result from a certain area, but learning those points of view and proof techniques might be extremely helpful in a different context. I believe the best of mathematics comes when two areas meet, and that wouldn't be possible without a good knowledge of different areas.

Comment: I also think that differential geometry uses more advanced abstract algebra than you might think. Also, not only advanced algebra is compulsory, so what about analysis, geometry or topology ? Certainly we can find research areas not using much of it.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I agree that it's good to be a 'rounded mathematician' but it's in the case that the person wouldn't forget 'the other' learnt fields since they won't be used so they will most probably be forgotten.

Comment: I don't mind this question very much, even if it could be perhaps worded better. There are plenty of things in a book like Hungerford that I think are almost completely unused in modern mathematics especially outside of algebra(i.e. I have never seen the Sylow theorems in any paper). I really cannot say the same for any other grad 1st-year or 2nd-year topic(i.e. Functional Analysis, Real Analysis, Complex Analysis, Differential Topology, Algebraic Topology, Riemannian Geometry).

Comment: The differential geometers I've known seemed to be quite knowledgeable in abstract algebra, and even with what little I know, it seems to me that a fair amount of algebra is needed for Lie groups, fiber bundles, homotopy and homology (and algebraic topology in general) applied to manifolds, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely be involved in teaching as well as research in all but a few cases.  And many fields can overlap considerably!  These core areas vary from school to school, but as someone with a graduate degree in math, you are generally expected to know something from various subjects and not just your own.  For example, I am a discrete mathematician, and haven't really used analysis much even though I was required to take it.  But I have taught Calculus several times, and I'm expected to have a rigorous understanding of the subject even if I'm not teaching delta-epsilon proofs.

Also as the comments have suggested, you will come across quite a bit of algebra in studying certain aspects of differential geometry.  There are quite a few connections to algebraic geometry, even an area called algebraic differential geometry.